# Two different WordPress post , two different ids but with same slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm stuck with some strange problem , Whenever user search for a post it first looks on a post , if a post is available it show the post but when post is not available it creates new post via code and gets the post content from other sites API . So everything is working perfectly until I find that there are some post whos have different ID but their slug are same  and when I open that post. WordPress single.php show the content of both page at same time.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to achieve and if you can show us some code as well.

Comment: ` if ( ! empty( get_query_var( 'subtitles' ) ) && ! get_page_by_title( str_replace( ' ', '-', get_query_var( 'subtitles' ) ), OBJECT,  'post' ) ) {

  $postarr = array(
   'post_type'   => 'post',
   'post_title'  => str_replace( ' ', '-', get_query_var( 'subtitles' ) ),
   'post_status' => 'publish',
  );
  wp_insert_post( $postarr );

 }`